# How do I load related entities on a sub class with Doctrine inheritance mapping?

Tags: symfony, inheritance, orm, doctrine

Doctrine has a couple of great options to provide your application with abstraction and performance features.

1. Pre-fetching related objects (by joining them)
2. Inheritance mapping in your entity model

Combining the two seems to be a bit problematic. I'm not even sure if Doctrine is able to handle complexity of this magnitude.
This will be the third area of discussion where my question really lies.

## 1. Pre-fetching related objects:

If I simply want to fetch all Supplier entities that are related to a RegularProduct, I'd do something like this in my Repository

**App\Repository\RegularProductRepository.php:**

```
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class RegularProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array The result
     */
    public function findWithSupplier() : array
    {
        $alias = "rp";

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias);

        $qb->addSelect("s"); // hydrates Supplier entity
        $qb->leftJoin($alias . ".supplier", "s");

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

This results in a single query on the database. Whenever I read the suppliers properties in a template it doesn't need to query the database again because the supplier entity is already stored in the ReguralProduct entity.

## 2. Inheritance mapping in your entity model:

In this example I show you the concept which I have implemented in my project.

**App\Entity\AbstractProductBase.php:**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "App\Repository\ProductBaseRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "s4_product")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name = "product_type", type = "string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"RegularProduct" = "RegularProduct", "AliasedProduct" = "AliasedProduct"})
 */
abstract class AbstractProductBase
{
    /**
     * ID
     *
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_id", type = "integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Name
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name = "product_name", type = "string", length = 128)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Created At
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name = "created_at_date", type = "datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /* ... getters & setters ... */
}
```

**App\Entity\RegularProduct.php:**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Entity\AliasedProduct;
use App\Entity\ProductDevice;
use App\Entity\Supplier;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "App\Repository\RegularProductRepository")
 */
class RegularProduct extends AbstractProductBase
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->aliasedProducts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->devices         = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Supplier
     *
     * Many Products have one Supplier
     *
     * @var Supplier
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Supplier", inversedBy = "products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "supplier_id")
     */
    protected $supplier;

    /**
     * Aliased Products
     *
     * One RegularProduct has Many AliasedProducts
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "AliasedProduct", mappedBy = "regularProduct")
     */
    protected $aliasedProducts;

    /**
     * Devices
     * 
     * Many Products have many Devices (with association class ProductDevice)
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "ProductDevice", mappedBy = "product", cascade = { "persist", "remove" })
     */
    protected $devices;

    /**
     * Set supplier
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Supplier $supplier
     * @return RegularProduct
     */
    public function setSupplier(Supplier $supplier = null)
    {
        $this->supplier = $supplier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get supplier
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\Supplier
     */
    public function getSupplier()
    {
        return $this->supplier;
    }

    /**
     * Add aliasedProduct
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\AliasedProduct $aliasedProduct
     * @return RegularProduct
     */
    public function addAliasedProduct(AliasedProduct $aliasedProduct)
    {
        $aliasedProduct->setRegularProduct($this);

        $this->aliasedProducts[] = $aliasedProduct;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove aliasedProduct
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\AliasedProduct $aliasedProduct
     */
    public function removeCopy(AliasedProduct $aliasedProduct)
    {
        $this->aliasedProducts->removeElement($aliasedProduct);
    }

    /**
     * Get aliasedProducts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAliasedProducts()
    {
        return $this->aliasedProducts;
    }

    /**
     * Add device
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\ProductDevice $device
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addDevice(ProductDevice $device)
    {
        $device->setProduct($this);

        $this->devices[] = $device;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove device
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\ProductDevice $device
     */
    public function removeDevice(ProductDevice $device)
    {
        $this->devices->removeElement($device);
    }

    /**
     * Get devices
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDevices()
    {
        return $this->devices;
    }
}
```

**App\Entity\AliasedProduct.php:**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use App\Entity\AbstractProductBase;
use App\Entity\RegularProduct;

/**
 * Aliased Product Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AliasedProduct extends AbstractProductBase
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Regular Product
     *
     * Many AliasedProducts have one RegularProduct
     *
     * @var \App\Entity\RegularProduct
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "RegularProduct", inversedBy = "aliasedProducts", fetch = "EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "original_product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
     */
    protected $regularProduct;

    /**
     * Set regularProduct
     *
     * @var \App\Entity\RegularProduct
     *
     * @return AliasedProduct
     */
    public function setRegularProduct(RegularProduct $regularProduct = null)
    {
        $this->regularProduct = $regularProduct;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\RegularProduct
     */
    public function getRegularProduct()
    {
        return $this->regularProduct;
    }

    /**
     * Get supplier
     *
     * @return Supplier
     */
    public function getSupplier()
    {
        return $this->regularProduct->getSupplier();
    }
}
```

## 3. Hydrating related entities on inherited classes

When I want to achieve this on a class with inheritance mapping it seems that I also need to join the Sub entity RegularProduct
In my result set will be both RegularProduct and AliasedProduct entities.

Executing the query in the Repository below results in a HydrationException with the message: `The parent object of entity result with alias 'd' was not found. The parent alias is 'rp'.`

**App\Repository\ProductBaseRepository.php:**

```
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use App\Entity\RegularProduct;

abstract class ProductBaseRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllWithDevices() : array
    {
        $alias = "pb"; // AbstractProductBase

        $qb->leftJoin(
            RegularProduct::class,
            "rp",
            "WITH",
            $qb->expr()->eq($alias,"p")
        );

        $qb->addSelect("d"); // hydrates ProductDevice entity

        $qb->leftJoin(
            "rp.devices",
            "d",
            "WITH",
            $qb->expr()->eq("rp", "d.product")
        );

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

I have tried to alter the query by adding `$qb->addSelect("rp")`. This solves getting the exception but poses a new problem; the results are not clean.
At this point the resulting array contain all RegularProducts twice, AliasedProducts once, and for each AliasedProduct there is a null variable.

Is it by any means possible to perform a query which only hydrates Devices on RegularProducts without added the `$qb->addSelect("rp")` line in my code?

Comment: You can use eager mode from doctrine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657870/eager-loading-of-related-entity-in-symfony-2

Comment: If only the solution would be that simple. maybe I should have included in my explanation. It's actually  more efficient to set fetch mode to extra_lazy

Comment: If you dont use eager mode from doctrine, you have to alter the query as you did, or do another query [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading). You have to add your select because you use extra_lazy mode.