# Doctrine and cascade fetch="EAGER"

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have three entities : `User` > `UserVersion` > `Color`. Each entity is connected with `fetch="EAGER"`.

**`User` class :**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var UserVersion[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\UserVersion",
     *     mappedBy="user",
     *     cascade={"persist"},
     *     fetch="EAGER",
     * )
     */
    protected $versions;
```

**`UserVersion` class :**

```
class UserVersion
{
    /**
     * @var Color
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Color",
     *     fetch="EAGER",
     * )
     */
    private $color;
```

But When I get user with `$entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find(2)` I have a join `User` > `UserVersion` **but not** `UserVersion` > `Color`.

I would like joins for my three entities. Is it possible or I have to do `$this->createQueryBuilder()` and manual joins ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657870/eager-loading-of-related-entity-in-symfony-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eager loading of related entity in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657870/eager-loading-of-related-entity-in-symfony-2)